# Proving a point exists on a twice differentiable function.

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:** Suppose that $f$ is twice differentiable on $(a,b)$ and that there are points $x_1\lt x_2\lt x_3$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f(x_1)\gt f(x_2)$ and $f(x_3)\gt f(x_2)$. Prove that there is a point $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f''(c)\gt 0$.

The part that is tripping me up is how I can use; $f(x_1)\gt f(x_2)$ and $f(x_3)\gt f(x_2)$ as part of the proof. Just before this I encountered a similar problem where we were seeking to prove the same thing only the conditions were: $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f(x_3)=0$. In this case it was a quick application of the **Rolle's Theorem**.

Now that we don't have them all conveniently equaling $0$, I believe we need to use the **Intermediate Value Theorem for Derivatives**. I am having trouble applying that in such a way to show that a point $c$ exists. Any help would be great.

The theorems mentioned above are as follows:

**Rolle's Theorem:** Suppose that $a,b\in \mathbb R$ with $a\lt b$. If $f$ is continuous on $[a.b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and if $f(a)=f(b)$, then $f'(c)=0$ for some $c\in (a,b)$.

**Intermediate Value Theorem for Derivatives:** Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ with $f'(a)\ne f'(b)$. If $y_0$ is a real number which lies between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$, then there is an $x_0 \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x_0)=y_0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By  $x_1 < x_2$ and $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$, by Mean value theorem (MVT), there exists a point $a \in (x_1,x_2)$ s.t. $f′(a) = \frac{f(x_2) − f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} < 0$.

By  $x_2 < x_3$ and $f(x_3) > f(x_2)$, by MVT, there exists a point $b \in (x_2,x_3)$ s.t. $f′(b) = \frac{f(x_3) − f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2} > 0$

Then apply MVT to $f'(x)$, there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f′′(c) = \frac{f′(b) − f′(a)}{b-a} > 0$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to do everything at once rather than split it up like this.